# Delete datastore entity from template

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

In my app i have a template that read data from datastore, the table is like this:

- name / surname / action
- john / doe     / (delete button)
- jack / bush    / (delete button)
- ...

i'm looking for the best pratices for associate the delete button to the relative entitie (row)

Someone can show me the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice woud be to use the entity id to perform the delete.

My recommendation would be to either store the ID in a hidden field, or put the ID as the name or value of the button.

Comment: i learn that we can append ?name=value to the /action for pass value..
/action?name=value